# no such table: paypal_expresstransaction

Tags: python, django, paypal-sandbox, django-oscar

Problem integrating paypal express in a django oscar store.

Added 'paypal' to installed apps and wrote template with the following code:

```
{% extends 'oscar/checkout/payment_details.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block payment_details %}
    <div class="well">
        <div class="sub-header">
        <h3>{% trans "PayPal Express" %}</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{% trans "Click on the below icon to use Express Checkout but where the shipping address and method is already chosen on the merchant site." %}</p>
    <div style="overflow:auto"><a href="{% url 'paypal-direct-payment' %}" title="{% trans "Pay with PayPal" %}"><img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/logo/PayPal_mark_37x23.gif" align="left" style="margin-right:7px;"></a>&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Upon clicking on the payment button I get this error: 
no such table: paypal_expresstransaction

Comment: I did, and got back "No migrations to apply."

Comment: But there should be since you added a new app with new models. Make sure that you are running `makemigrations` first.

Comment: can you double check and see if `paypal` is indeed in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Definitely it is in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Also what is strange is I tried running the sandbox django-oscar-paypal and seem to be getting the same: no such table: paypal_expresstransaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try run migrate with specify app

```
./manage.py makemigrations paypal
```

and then just migrate.

Comment: What is the difference between `makemigrations` and `makemigrations app_name`? The former was not picking up any changes, but when I used the latter, there were two changes and the same problem OP had went away.